# How to call VF on the Detail Button from Opportunity

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button

Classic:

```
document.location="/apex/CreateCaseRequest?oppid={!Opportunity.Id}";
```

I created a new Button for Lightning : did not work

```
    {!URLFOR('apex/CreateCaseRequest', null, [
SourceID = Opportunity.Id
]
)}
```

CreateCaseRequest is VF page :

```
 <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CreateCaseController"  action="{!Case}">
<script>
var theQueryString = '';
theQueryString = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.oppid}';
if(theQueryString != ''){
alert('Thank you.');
top.location = '/' + theQueryString;  
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Not sure if this can be done using only the new Button of I need to create a lightning action on this.

Comment: Try this:-

 {!URLFOR('apex/CreateCaseRequest', null, [ oppid= Opportunity.Id ]
)}

In URLFOR, You were using the wrong parameter name to pass id.

When it comes Lightning, URLFOR will not always come and rescue you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the standard controller, you can link the VF page directly using the Visualforce option, (instead of the URL option) and choosing your VF page. The parameter for the opportunity will be simply "Id" (e.g. `{!Opportunity.Id}` or `{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}`).